# Oozie sample on EMR

Tags: oozie, emr

Can someone please explain me what is a name node and job tracker for oozie action when working on EMR(EMRFS). I do understand that name node is specific to hdfs but if i'm using EMRFS then what should be the value of it in oozie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name-node` should be the namenode FQDN:port or IP:port of the EMR master where HDFS namenode daemon runs. `job-tracker` is the YARN resource managers address. They remain unchanged with or without EMRFS because OOZIE still uses HDFS(not S3). Based on the Action , the YARN containers(mappers/reducers) might use EMRFS and you do not need to set anything for it.

You can see this ports list to find the necessary ports for EMR : 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-4.2.0/emr-release-differences.html#w2ab1c66c15

You can also find them in `fs.default.name` ,`mapred.job.tracker` settings of core-site.xml / yarn-site.xml  / mapred-site.xml files.